# How to use regex to remove a particular pattern of words with numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of words which generate different patterns of similar words through different audio file, I want to use regex pattern to get that pattern of words and remove it for the actual text. For example I have the text below:

```
text = "Yeah Cool\nSpeaker 100:00:03Uh, you know, when you score three goals, you expect to win a game, you know, but, uh,"
```

All I want to do is a regex pattern that can detect **Speaker 100:00:03** and other similar pattern, depending on the audio file, at times i might have **Speaker 100:00:01** which looks different from the first one but they are similar

Is there a better way to do this?

I was using string `replace` which is not a universal solution
which is this:

```
new_text  = text.replace('Speaker 000:00:00', '')
```

This is the expected result after applying regex which is what I'm expecting.

```
text = "Yeah Cool Uh, you know, when you score three goals, you expect to win a game, you know, but, uh,"
```

Comment: So you know Regex might be a solution, why don't you even try to build a regex that, at least, matches the text you're looking for? We don't even know if you're aware that you have to `import re` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact format of the timestamp, `re.sub` with the following pattern should work

```
>>> re.sub('\nSpeaker \d{1,3}:\d{2}:\d{2}', ' ', text)
'Yeah Cool Uh, you know, when you score three goals, you expect to win a game, you know, but, uh,'
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple regular expression:

```
import re
text = "Yeah Cool\nSpeaker 100:00:03Uh, you know, when you score three goals, you expect to win a game, you know, but, uh,"
re.sub(r'\nSpeaker \d\d\d:\d\d:\d\d', ' ', text)                                                
# 'Yeah Cool Uh, you know, when you score three goals, you expect to win a game, you know, but, uh,'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
“\nSpeaker \d{3}:\d{2}:\d{2}”
```

`\d` detects a digit and `{3}` means three times... so `\d{3}` means three digits.

Try [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) it’s a great site to experiment with reflex.